# C# help, overloading a method

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I have one last thing to add to my assignment before im finished.

This is a part of my code:

```
static decimal FahrToCels(int fahrenheit) //Metod för konvertering av Fahrenheit(F) till Celsius(C)
{
    decimal celsius = (decimal)((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9; // Matematisk uträkning för F till C. 
    return Math.Round (celsius, 1); //Lagrar ett decimal tal avrundat till 1 decimal och lagrar i celsius
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Vänligen ange temperatur till bastun och tryck enter: "); //skriver ut meddelande

    do
        int fahr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Omvandlar string och lagrar användarens inmatning i en int fahrenheit
        decimal celsius = FahrToCels(fahr); // Metoden FahrToCels konverterar inmatad temperatur till celsius och lagrar i decimal celsius
```

As can be seen, ive created a method, that is later used after the user is told to enter degrees in fahrenheit. The method converts the entered number to celsius.

Now the last thing im told to do is by overloading the method, make it possible for the user to enter zero(0) and by doing that randomly generate a number  before that number goes into the fahrenheit to celsius converting method. Im guessing the generated numbet has to be like between 140-195 because the user needs to enter zero until the generated number equals to 73-77 after converting to celsius!

I know how to generate a random number, and i think i understand what overloading does, but im totally lost on how to do this one...

Comment: `float` is a better choice than `int` or `double` for continuous quantities like temperature. Also, please give us an example of what “to enter zero” means. You know that zero is a perfectly valid temperature, right?

Comment: @DourHighArch  This is a school assignment and i find it a little odd. My code works perfect and does what it is supposed to. But the last thing the assignment wants me to to is " The user should also be able to enter a zero(0) to randomly generate a temperature. If this happens, no value should be sent to the method, this can be solved by method overloading"   So I guess if the user enters the number zero, a random temperature should be generated.  The rest of my code consists of some if and else to get the user to enter the correct temperature.

Comment: @DourHighArch The reason for the int variable is because the assignment said it should be stored as an int first. For some reason.

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to create a function under (or over) the method inside the class that takes no arguments. Nothing else special is required. When you want to call `FahrToCels()`, you have the option to call either method based on the type and quantity of the arguments.

```
    static decimal FahrToCels ()
    {
        // Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method like this

```
    static decimal FahrToCels(string value) //note value is of type 'string'
    {
        //your implementation goes here, check if value is 'zero'
    }
```

This solves your requirement to use method overloading, event though I find it a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other possible concerns: Overloading a method has nothing to do with specific parameter values (unless you are using different types, e.g. short, int, long). In your case: "if the parameter value is 0 then return a random number" is not something solvable by overloading.

Now after reading your comment on the question; you could create a method that doesn't take any parameters `static decimal FahrToCels()` and call that in case you read a `0` from the input. This new method would then generate a random value and convert that.

Personal opinion: I'm not gonna comment on how reasonable that assignment is. The more standard case would be to use an `if` statement to decide if the input was `0` and if so generate a random value and pass that to the method you already have. But I might be missing something here.

Comment: Even if im a newbie in programming, im aware that the assignment is strange....  Yes, making a method that doesnt take any parameters is what it tells me I could do. But how do i create this? I know how to generate random numbers, but how do i call for the method when the user enters 0? Because as of now when entering zero, is converts to -17,8 degree celsius. If i were to use if-statements, where would i put it? Because of now it automatically uses the convertion method when entering any given number

Comment: you would need an `if` stament (that's why I was questioning the assignment). so it would be something like: `if(fahr == 0) { <call method without params> } else { <call the regular method> }`

Comment: Yes that seems like a solution. But how would I first make it generate the random number that then continues to the convering method? I need to make a new method, that has a number generator and the converter in it I guess?

Comment: One possibility would be: generate the random number (either with or without an extra method) and use it as a parameter for calling the other `FahrToCels` method. Then return what you get from that.